# Ember.js Creating a new route in ember.js always lead to default index.html file

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, routes

I am new at learning ember.js I have followed some tutorials but I don't know why It doesn't work for me.
What I would like is to create a new route with games: `http://localhost:4200/jeux`
so I have done :

```
ember g route jeux
```

To create a new route "/jeux"
I have completed this new page with jeux.hbs:

```
{{page-title "Jeux"}}
<p>La page des jeux-vidéos</p>
```

Now I don't know why http://localhost:4200/jeux is still leading to the default index.html page
[image of http://localhost:4200][1]
[image of http://localhost:4200/jeux][2]
Thanks for the Help!
Here are some images that can help to understand my project
(it is a simple project that I have generated with "`ember new the project name`")

```
[image of file "router.js"][3]
[basic default "index.html"][4]
[the evironment.js file][5]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAzuf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBrFB.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQunM.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEa93.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaXfp.png
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not attach your code as an image, instead use codeblock.

Comment: Welcome! Please always remember to check the preview of your post before posting it. In this case, all your links are not formatted properly. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 1):

You've made one mistake in your `router.js` file.
It should look like this:

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('jeux');
});
```

Looking at [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/), `/` before route name is unnecessary, you probably tried to use syntax with path different than route name like

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('jeux', {path:'/jeux'});
});
```